# Angular2 Spring boot date serialization

Tags: java, json, spring, angular, jackson

I'm making a REST API with an Angular2 frontend. In my Spring configuration for jackson I have set this `spring.jackson.date-format=EEE MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz (zzzz)` because I use the bootstrap-datepicker plugin which outputs dates like this: `Wed May 31 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Daylight Time)`.
When I try to post a date to a DTO which has variables like this one `private Date defaultDatetime;` The REST API returns a 400 Bad request error.

```
{"timestamp":"mer. mai 03 2017 14:16:47",
"status":400,
"error":"Bad Request",
"exception":"org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException",
"message":"Could not read document: Can not construct instance of java.util.Date from String value '2017-05-01T22:00:00.000Z': not a valid representation (error: Failed to parse Date value '2017-05-01T22:00:00.000Z': Unparseable date: \"2017-05-01T22:00:00.000Z\")\n at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@77b19daf; line: 1, column: 68] (through reference chain: ch.heigvd.form.api.dto.FormDTO[\"fields\"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->ch.heigvd.form.api.dto.field.DateFieldDTO[\"defaultDate\"]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException: Can not construct instance of java.util.Date from String value '2017-05-01T22:00:00.000Z': not a valid representation (error: Failed to parse Date value '2017-05-01T22:00:00.000Z': Unparseable date: \"2017-05-01T22:00:00.000Z\")\n at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@77b19daf; line: 1, column: 68] (through reference chain: ch.heigvd.form.api.dto.FormDTO[\"fields\"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->ch.heigvd.form.api.dto.field.DateFieldDTO[\"defaultDate\"])",
"path":"/api/forms"}
```

Any idea what kind of date-format I should put for jackson deserializatrion? Or should I change the format directly in the frontend?

**Update**

I got it working with a custom serializer. This is the configuration in the properties file.

> spring.jackson.date-format=ch.heigvd.form.configuration.CustomJsonDateDeserializer
>   spring.jackson.serialization.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS=false

This is the serializer:

```
public class CustomJsonDateDeserializer extends ISO8601DateFormat {

    @Override
    public StringBuffer format(Date date, StringBuffer toAppendTo, FieldPosition fieldPosition) {
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");
        toAppendTo.append(format.format(date));
        return toAppendTo;
    }

    @Override
    public Date parse(String source, ParsePosition pos) {
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");
        try {
            return format.parse(source);
        } catch (ParseException var4) {
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that boostrsrap-datepicker returns js `Date()` object. When you make backend request it makes `JSON.stringify(date)`, that returns string as `"2017-05-03T15:07:34.056Z"`. Same is reflected in error message that you got. So set Jackson format to be able to parse that format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do either of the two options, 
Option 1: 
since it returns ISOFormat, write your own deserializer.

```
@JsonDeserialize(using=CustomerDateAndTimeDeserialize .class)
public class CustomJsonDateDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Date>
{
    @Override
    public Date deserialize(JsonParser jsonparser,
            DeserializationContext deserializationcontext) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {

        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
        String date = jsonparser.getText();
        try {
            return format.parse(date);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

    }
}
```

Annotate each setter everywhere with

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = CustomJsonDateDeserializer.class)
```

Option 2: 
Change your format to match ISO String format.

```
spring.jackson.date-format=YYYY-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'
```

Comment: I tried option 2 but I still got an error at first. I edited the property to `spring.jackson.date-format=YYYY-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'` and it seems to work now. Thank you!

Comment: I just realised that the date deserialized by jackson is not the same as the one given. When the frontend sends `2017-05-16T22:00:00.000Z`, it always deserialize it to `2017-01-02T23:00:00.000Z`. Should I try option 1?

Comment: @Servietsky : strange, yes Option 1 is full proof :). i will also try this replicating ur issue.

Comment: How can I apply the option 1 to every class. Every date I will deserialize will have the same format.

Comment: I got it working with some kind of custom serializer. I also replaced the YYYY with yyyy, I don't know if it changed anything. You can see it in my original post.