# Angular datepicker how to parse to Java Date?

Tags: angular, spring, spring-boot

I have a little todo app with an Angular frontend and Spring Boot as backend. I'm very new to Spring Boot and might need a further explanation. Thanks for your understanding.

My problem is to parse the date format I get from the angular datepicker component to type Date. This is the current error I'm getting:

```
"JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.util.Date` out of START_OBJECT token; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.util.Date` out of START_OBJECT token
        at[Source:(PushbackInputStream);line:1,column:73](through reference chain:todo.ToDo["dueDate"])"
```

I have looked for a solution and I think I found one but I do not quite understand how to implement it in my situation: [Angular2 Spring boot date serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43763012/angular2-spring-boot-date-serialization)

As I'm currently receiving the post from the user as a ToDo entity:

```
@PostMapping("/todos")
    ToDo newToDo(@RequestBody ToDo newToDo) {
        return repository.save(newToDo);
    }
```

How should I extract the date input by the user? I would then parse the date and after that save it. In my head it should work then...

Thanks for any help or suggestions

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Comment: show the `@ RequestBody` and JSON

Answer (score 1):

You may need to use `LocalDateSerializer` and `LocalDateDeserializer` for this.

ToDo class.

```
 public class ToDo {
  @JsonDeserialize(using = LocalDateDeserializer.class)
  @JsonSerialize(using = LocalDateSerializer.class)
  private LocalDate dueDate;

  // getters and setters

 }
```

LocalDateDeserializer.java

```
   import java.time.LocalDate;

   import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser;
   import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext;
   import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdDeserializer;

  public class LocalDateDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<LocalDate> {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

protected LocalDateDeserializer() {
    super( LocalDate.class );
}

@Override
  public LocalDate deserialize( JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt ) {
    try {
        return LocalDate.parse( jp.readValueAs( String.class ) );
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        return null;
    }
}
}
```

LocalDateSerializer.java

```
 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.time.LocalDate;
 import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.StdSerializer;

public class LocalDateSerializer extends StdSerializer<LocalDate>
{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public LocalDateSerializer()
{
    super( LocalDate.class );
}

  @Override
  public void serialize( LocalDate value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider sp ) 
  throws IOException, JsonProcessingException
    {
        gen.writeString( value.format( DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE ) );
  }
}
```

And also you should pass date as a string Ex: "2019-02-01". Passing Date object from the front-end is not a good practice.

```
    import { Component,Input } from '@angular/core';
   import {TodoService} from './todo.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
   templateUrl: './app.component.html', 
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
 })
  export class AppComponent {
  title = 'ToDoApp';

constructor(private todoService: TodoService) {
}

@Input() toDoData = {name: '', dueDate: Date};

addToDo() {
    this.toDoData.dueDate = // formatted date
    this.todoService.addToDo(this.toDoData).subscribe((result) => {
        this.todoService.addToDo(this.toDoData);
        console.log(this.toDoData.dueDate);
    });
}

convertToMilliseconds(dueDate: DateConstructor) {
    return dueDate.valueOf();
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I've created the two classes you suggested. I do not get an error when I create a new todo on the UI but the date value is null.
My ToDo class file: https://pastebin.com/gUKYyCEE

Comment: Sure, thanks for helping me out!
todo.service.ts: https://pastebin.com/NXeC4xj5
app.component.ts: https://pastebin.com/bMqe39XD
html: https://pastebin.com/EQC9asPq

Comment: see my modified answer. I have tested this and verified :)